# Layer NOT shown in Geonode

Tags: security, tomcat, oauth, geoserver, geofence

A layer is displayed in *Geonode* when *admin*  is logged in *GeoServer*. When the *admin* logs off in *GeoServer* the layer is not displayed in *Geonode*.

[image]

It seems like *oauth* configuration of geoserver-geonode is not done properly (the default settings are not changed) which I am not able to solve.

The geoserver log shows errors/exceptions as follows:

```
ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Could not find layer geonode:nepalNationalParks
.
.
WARN [geofence.cache] - org.geoserver.geofence.cache.CachedRuleReader$NoAuthException: Can't auth user [admin]
WARN [geoserver.security] - Failed login, user admin from 192.168.10.66
```

My System Configuration is GeoNode 3.1.0 , GeoServer 2.16.2 installed on Ubuntu 18.04. The larger log file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x16iut1t329p5yw/geoserver_log4.txt?dl=0).

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tekson Thank You for your suggestion.
I tried to play with GeoFence Rules as well. However, I think the problem was due to mis-configuration in OAuth setting.  The issue was solved when I re-installed Geonode with proper IP Address and URLs (and did not altered the GeoFenceing Rules).

I followed [Geonode installation guide(ubuntu 18.04)](https://docs.geonode.org/en/master/install/advanced/core/index.html#ubuntu-18-04). In my previous installation,  mis-configuration might had happened around section
*Update the settings in order to update GeoNode and GeoServer services running on a public IP or hostname* particularly in Step 3 (*Update OAuth2 configuration in order to hit the new hostname*).

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to add new geofench rule from GeoFence Data Rules menu `(GeoFence Data Rules>>Add new rule>>)` as below,

```
Priority: 0
Role: *
Username: *
Service: *
Request: *
Workspace: *
Layer: *
Access: ALLOW
```

Or you can apply the required role for specific serice, workspace, or layer by just changing the parameter.